# How to read audio in C (i.e. FFT or buckets)?

Tags: c, audio, visualization, c99

TL;DR: How do I read audio from a file in C (not C++)?

### Context

I'm a young programmer and I want to make a project that does audio visualisation like this!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O3nm0Nvbi4

To do this, I need to read from an audio file.

I must use C, which is unfortunate as a lot of the audio sampling libraries/GUI libraries are written for C++.

Are there any libraries for audio sampling and creating the GUI to display these bars for the audio visualisation using vanilla C (C99)?
I've read through this tutorial: https://2captiv8.blogspot.com/2016/06/howto-design-code-music-visualization-visualizer-audio-linux-c-sdl-fourier.html

### Optional info

Eventually, after hours of research I've been hinted at the SDL library or libsndfile or CSFML, however I'm not too sure how to exactly use these libraries to read audio sample DATA and sync it with the music being played.

For the Fourier Transform I've researched that FFTW is really good for C. But what I'm struggling is actually getting that audio data to be fed into FFTW and how exactly do I perform the FFT every few seconds to make the visualisation not static but actually moving and dynamic.

Comment: write some code to open up a WAV format audio file and figure out how to populate an array from the payload ... feed this floating point array into a FFT call which will return a new array where each element contains a complex number ... iterate across this new array and for each element calculate the magnitude of that complex number then plot these magnitudes .. I suggest you invest time doing this then when you resurface worry about putting above into a loop to not consume entire first array but instead only take a set of array elements to get sent to the FFT call .. advance begin/end repeat

Comment: First question: Why not use C++ if that's where the good libraries are? That being said there's surely innumerable C libraries around as doing FFT in software is nothing new.